# Calculating SVD of a complex matrix (Golub Reinsch method)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, svd

I am trying to implement the SVD of a complex matrix in Matlab (not allowed to use build-in functions, e.g., svd, qr).

I have implemented svd using the Golub-Reiasch method for real valued matrix, however, I am having problem to extend it to a complex matrix.

I am doing following steps in my code:

1- decompose the matrix $A$ to get a bidiagonal matrix $B$.

2- perform QR iterations on  $B$ until the super-diagonal entries are small. this step includes Givens rotation.

The code works for real matrix but not for complex. I have implemented the complex version of Givens rotation, however, I have noted that the diagonal entries of $B$ are complex number, whereas I am expecting real numbers.

I would appreciate if someone could advise me how to proceed to implement the svd.

Comment: A common mistake in matlab (and in this particular context): in general, you should be using `'` as opposed to `.'`.  Also: did you check to see if the complex numbers on the diagonal have a small imaginary part?

Comment: thank you for the comment. I have double checked to be sure about those kind of mistakes.
The imaginary parts are significant. This is indeed due to the nature of complex Givens Rotation

Comment: Okay, it seems like any debugging is going to require a closer look.  Do you have a link to the reference that you're using for the Golub-Reinsch algorithm?

Comment: As reference, I tried to test the codes in this book: (scientific computing) www.unige.ch/~gander/programs.php   in particular the code GolubReinsch.m

Comment: In the meantime downloaded the following paper (report), but there is no description of the algorithm. Seems this is the only work available on complex SVD.    paper: "Algorithm 358 for Singular Value Decomposition of a complex matrix"